# Cannot get brightness keys to work on Ubuntu 22.04 / Lenovo IdeaPad 5

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, brightness, backlight

I have IdeaPad 5 15IAL7 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, kernel `5.19.0-46-generic`. It is Intel Core i5 with Intel Iris XE graphics.
Special <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys all work, except the brightness. Volume is changing with appropriate indication on screen. It tried everything I could find:

1. `xev` does not display any events when brightness keys are pressed, however, it detects volume;
2. `showkey` does not detect brightness, but detects volume;
3. `acpi_listen` does not detect brightness keys, but detects volume;
4. `evtest` does not detect brightness either. But it shows this:

```
Event code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN)
Event code 225 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP)
```

5. Adjusting GRUB parameters like `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` does nothing (tried other combinations also)
6. `xbacklight` prints "No outputs have backlight property"
7. `brightnessctl` shows:

```
Device 'intel_backlight' of class 'backlight':
    Current brightness: 21333 (100%)
    Max brightness: 21333
```

8. If I change setting directly, it changes brightness:

`echo 10666 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

9. I can change brightness with a slider in settings, so it means it works, the problem is just with keys.

I suppose this my be problem with hardware support in kernel, but maybe something can be done with it?

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:46a6] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3af2]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after updating to kernel version 6.